# jQuery Mobile has an unexpected animation at the bottom

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-animate

I have not done anything that should make it animate the screen up with the word LOADING but when I slide my finger up on the screen I get like a bottom toolbar/footer that shows the word:

> loading

Here is my code you will see nothing in there that shows loading.

JS File

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    //$.mobile.pushStateEnabled = true;
    //$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
});


        $(function(){

            var menuStatus;
            $("#content").animate({
                    marginLeft: "165px",
                  }, 300, function(){menuStatus = true});

            // Show menu
            $("a.showMenu").click(function(){
                if(menuStatus != true){             
                $(".ui-page-active").animate({
                    marginLeft: "165px",
                  }, 300, function(){menuStatus = true});
                  return false;
                  } else {
                    $(".ui-page-active").animate({
                    marginLeft: "0px",
                  }, 300, function(){menuStatus = false});
                    return false;
                  }
            });


            $('#menu, #content').live("swipeleft", function(){
                if (menuStatus){    
                $("#content").animate({
                    marginLeft: "0px",
                  }, 300, function(){menuStatus = false});
                  }
            });

            $('#content').live("swiperight", function(){
                if (!menuStatus){   
                $("#content").animate({
                    marginLeft: "165px",
                  }, 300, function(){menuStatus = true});
                  }
            });


});
```

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>SITE</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jmobile-animate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
</head> 

<body>
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#home" class="contentLink">Dashboard <span class="icon"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#page1" class="contentLink">Subpage 1 <span class="icon"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#page2" class="contentLink">Subpage 2 <span class="icon"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#page3" class="contentLink">Subpage 3 <span class="icon"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div id="content">
    <div class="hbg"><img src="images/small-logo.png" style="display:block;margin:2px auto 0 auto;"/></div>
</div>




</body>

<div data-role="footer" id="footer"> 
    <h4>&copy; 2012 SITE</h4> 
</div> 
</html>
```

Comment: I'm guessing it must be in the jmobile-animate.js or app.js files, try searching for the word 'loading' in those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you have included jquery mobile js.So I assume that you really need some jquery mobile functionality though I dont see any jquery mobile specific attributes like `data-role="page",data-role="content`" etc in your code.Along with the jquery mobile js,you have to inclide the jquery mobile css also ."Loading" text that you are seeing is from the jquery mobile loading message div.It is initially hidden through css and will be shown when `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(`) is being called

Add this line before you load main.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
```

Or if you dont need jquery mobile functionality, you can remove the script tag for jquery mobile js.

Just noticed another thing in your code.The footer div is outside body tag.Please add it inside the body tag if that was unintentional.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js"></script>
```